# Web farm names in Kentico

Tags: kentico, kentico-13

In my Kentico Xperience 13 website developed using .Net 6, I can see that the web farm for my live site is not named as it is supposed to be: https://docs.xperience.io/configuring-xperience/setting-up-web-farms/configuring-web-farm-servers.

It should be named `JohnD_MyLive_AutoExternalWeb` (JohnD being my machine name, MyLive the virtual application to access my live site at https://localhost/MyLive).
It keeps being named `JohnD_AutoExternalWeb` which is an issue as it impacts all my URL links (instead of being `https://localhost/MyLive/Home`, it is `https://localhost/Home`), medias and attachments (instead of `https://localhost/MyLive/getattachment/1234`, it is `https://localhost/getAttachment/1234`).

How can I fix that? I have checked the Sites App, my administration domaine name and my presentation URLs are good. Is there any settings somewhere else?

Thank you

Comment: The webfarm server name has no impact on the links. This sounds more like IIS setup - what is the web site and virtual app configuration? What is set as the Physical path for your virtual app? I just tested it and the web farm server names are working fine as well as they do not have any impact on the links...

Comment: Thank you. From VS, I follow what is described here: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/do-you-have-to-publish-net-core and I can acccess https://localhost/MyLive. However all my images, links in my pages are missing the MyLive domain. the The physical path is just pointing to the top folder of my live site in my D: drive. The virtual path of the application is correctly pointing to /MyLive.

Comment: The web farm was an indicator that K13 is not considering MyLive as the virtual application. My presentation URL is fine in the admin site. My application in IIS is also having the correct virtual path. I don't see what could explain this issue I have.

Comment: Hello Juraj, I tried for the DancingGoat core website which was targeting .Net3.1 initially to see if it was my project or a configuration issue: Updating it  to K13 v13.0.99, targeting .Net6 and recompiling everything using VS17.5.2 and I have the same error as I have in my project: Getmedia, links broken, web farm not correctly named. I also tried to update to target .Net7 framework but same issue and the Nuget packages in the DancingGoatCore project do not work with net7.0. Hope it helps to narrow the problem.

Comment: Each .NET Core project can have different startup so the forum link you posted works for Dancing Goat project but might not work for your project. I would say this depends on how the front end app is initialized. I would maybe recommend to follow recommended setup and use separate IIS site for admin and separate for live site app. Do not use virtual applications in the IIS.

Comment: Sure, but it worked fine before the udpate so this update could have caused some breaking changes.

Comment: @jurajo I have replicated my website on a completed different machine using the former version of VS (17.3.6) without having .Net7 installed on it and it works perfectly fine (getmedia, links, webfarm names) so it really sounds like an issue with .Net7...

Answer (score 1):

The webfarm name doesn't matter or have any impact on what URL is generated. The issue with your set up is you have a virtual application you're using and your URLs are not properly working because of it. You may want to share how you have IIS set up and what your site structure is within IIS. In most cases the main site displays the public facing website and a virtual application is set for the CMS.

So something like so:

`example.com = MVC site`  
`exapmle.com/cms = CMS site (vitrual application)`

Using the above, the following settings in your site would be as such:

`Presentation URL = https://example.com`
`Admin URL = example.com/cms`

[Cross posted on Kentico DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/web-farm-name-for-live-site-is-incorrect)